# The repeated fields in a protobuf message is empty in a POST api in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, protocol-buffers, repeat

As the title said, when I try to post a message (which is generated by protobuf message) from a react application to ASP.NET Core, the backend cannot receive the repeated fields (empty).

The following is the payload of a post action from the browser:

```
{ "strs": [ "test1", "test2" ] }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQJWi.png)

But in the POST API of ASP.NET Core, the body is just empty:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zZP6.png)

The protobuf message is very simple:

```
message TestArray {
    repeated string strs = 1;
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Part of the generated TestArray class in C#:

```
using pb = global::Google.Protobuf;
using pbc = global::Google.Protobuf.Collections;
using pbr = global::Google.Protobuf.Reflection;

// ...

public sealed partial class TestArray : pb::IMessage<TestArray>

// ...

private readonly pbc::RepeatedField<string> strs_ = new pbc::RepeatedField<string>();

// ...

    public pbc::RepeatedField<string> Strs {
      get { return strs_; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the Details of  TestArray in your api?

Comment: [HttpPost("testarray")]
        public void TestArray(TestArray tests)
        {
            TestArray temp = tests;
        }

Comment: Soory I didn't get how to insert code into the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-6.0#lists) and created the model as below:

```
public class TestArray
    {        
        public RepeatedField<string> Strs { get; set; }
    }
```

Tested with postman:

[image]

It seems binded successfully,so I asked you for the details of TestArray class to check what's wrong

I think you could create a DTO and add the necessary data to the instance of TestArray class

```
public sealed partial class TestArray 
    {
        

        private readonly RepeatedField<string> strs_ = new RepeatedField<string>();



        public RepeatedField<string> Strs
        {
            get { return strs_; }
        }
    }
    public class SomeDto
    {
        public  string[] Strs { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(SomeDto dto)
        {
            var testarr = new TestArray();
            testarr.Strs.Add(dto.Strs);
            return Ok();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ruikai, thank you. I have edited the question and added the C# code generated from proto file. It seems no difference with yours.

Comment: I checked the class you provied, It has difference between the class I've shown, the private attribute strs_ is always {[ ]}  without other settings during modelbinding ,and the public attribute always return the value of private attribute (So it will always retrun null whatever you passed to the controller)

Comment: Jsut try to modify the class as  what I've shown and try again

Comment: Thank you Ruikai. Definitely you are right. And I think I have understood the reason why protoc generated the repeated fields to private member and only give get property. The list itself is private so you cannot replace it with the other one but you can operate the list (add or something else). I think I should not modify the generated C# class. Now the problem is that why ASP.net core didn't deserialize the HTT post payload to the object rightly.

Comment: What about create a DTO to bind the array and other properties to it then  add the data to your TestArray obj?I've updated my answer,please check it